# Python - How to handle Cognito client exceptions in Boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

How am I supposed to handle AWS Cognito exceptions? I have this code below for handling an exception, but this feels weird, because if client initialization fails then I'm not sure what happens.

function.py

```
def post(self, request):
    try:
        client = boto3.client("cognito-idp", region_name=settings.COGNITO_AWS_REGION)
        response = client.sign_up(
            ClientId=os.getenv(settings.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID),
            Username=request.data['username'],
            Password=request.data['password'],
            UserAttributes=[{"Name": "email", "Value": request.data['email']}],
        )
        request.data['uuid'] = response['UserSub']

        if not response['UserConfirmed']:
            return Response(dict(error="Cognito did not return \'UserConfirmed\' attribute as true",
                                 user_msg=generic_error_message), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    except client.exceptions.UsernameExistsException as e:
        return Response(dict(error=e, user_msg='Sorry! This username is already taken.'),
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the docs list the exceptions here:

[image]

But first you have to create a CognitoIdentityProvider:

[image]

Which I do and define as `client`. Is this the proper way to handle Cognito exceptions?

Comment: client initialization error is handled with boto3 error. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: @shimo so everything else is fine?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by everything else?

Comment: sorry I mean the exception handling from creating user sent to the `client`. Does that look like it won't break?

Comment: I'm not sure which error to catch but I often use `except Exception as e:` for except any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you're handling it is the correct way. Rather than the generic `except Exception as e`, a better option is to catch the `ClientError` (`from botocore.exceptions import ClientError`) and parse the error code. Your exception handling though is more specific so I would stick with that. It also seems that's what the [boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html) recommends.

Answer (score 0):

Replace {EXCEPTION} with your specific exception.

```
import botocore


try:
    client = boto3.client("cognito-idp", region_name=settings.COGNITO_AWS_REGION)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
    if error.response["Error"]["Code"] != "{EXCEPTION}":
        raise
```

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions are part of the client object. My code works:

```
cog_client = boto3.client("cognito-idp")
try:
    response = cog_client.initiate_auth(AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH', AuthParameters=authParameters,
                                ClientId=cognito_clientid)

except cog_client.exceptions.UserNotFoundException as e:
    send_notification("User not found exception!")
```

In your code, you should create the client outside the try to capture the exceptions from the call using the client. The adjusted code below /should/ work.

```
def post(self, request):
    cog_client = boto3.client("cognito-idp", region_name=settings.COGNITO_AWS_REGION)
    try:
        response = cog_client.sign_up(
            ClientId=os.getenv(settings.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID),
            Username=request.data['username'],
            Password=request.data['password'],
            UserAttributes=[{"Name": "email", "Value": request.data['email']}],
        )
        request.data['uuid'] = response['UserSub']

    except client.exceptions.UsernameExistsException as e:
        return Response(dict(error=e, user_msg='Sorry! This username is already taken.'),
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```